# Vs code select text between quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a vast array list like below

```
$data= [
        'user_name' => 's',
        'user_place' => 'a',
        'address_list_code' => 's',
        'block_number' => 3,
];
```

so I want to replace the key string with all uppercase.I know to convert selected text to uppercase using vs code shortcut `Ctl+Alt+u` and it works.
But I want to select only all keys in between a single quote and make it uppercase so the expected output is

```
[
        'USER_NAME' => 's',
        'USER_PLACE' => 'a',
        'ADDRESS_LIST_CODE' => 's',
        'BLOCK_NUMBER' => 3,
];
```

Even I tried this extension but not suceded to select all text in between single quotes

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select&ssr=false#version-history

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m82ycfxw/
I made a normal JS code to convert the desired text to upper case.

This might be a temporary thing but I hope this will work for you.

```js
let str = `
$data= [
        'user_name' => 's',
        'user_place' => 'a',
        'address_list_code' => 's',
        'block_number' => 3,
]
`;

var regex = /'[a-z_]+' =>/g;
str = str.replace(regex, foundText => {
  return foundText.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(str);
```

Just change the `str` variable. Put all your complete data object inside backticks (`  `)and run the code.

Comment: i need without code .I am looking for vscode shortcut.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) could help.

- Place cursors at the start of the lines where you want to Uppercase text
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move to the next `'`
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors**
- with **MoveBy: Move cursors based on regex** move to the next `'`
- with **SelectBy: Mark positions of cursors** (create selections)
- execute: **Transform to Uppercase**
- `Esc` to exit multi Cursor

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this natively:

1. In `settings.json`, temporarily remove `_` as a word separators (e.g. `"editor.wordSeparators": "!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?,`) (Notice no `_`)
   .
2. Place cursors at beginnings of all desired lines.
3. Right arrow to move all cursors within the quotes.
4. Execute command `expand selection`.  Since you turned off `_` as a word delimiter, this will expand to fill the quotes; otherwise, all the keys would need to have the same number of words for this to work.
5. Execute `upper case`.
6. In `settings.json` re-add `_` to word separators.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Find and Replace.  See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDmkkL/1)

Find: `(^\s+')([^']*)'`
Replace: `$1\U$2'`

The `\U` will uppercase the following capture group `$2`.

Starting the find at the beginning of the line with `^` makes it easy to target just the "keys" (the first `'`-delimmited strings) and not the other following strings.